# How to prevent PyCharm's "Find in Files" to search the Python interpreter libraries?

Tags: python, pycharm, full-text-search

I am trying to find some pattern within files like my project's `setup.py` / `setup.cfg`', `rio.yaml`.  ***Our*** code ..   So within the `Find in Files` dialog I selected the `Directory` option.  However the `python` libraries are *still* being searched:

[image]

That was a surprise: I had expected those to only show up if the `Project` were selected.  So how can the Python libraries be excluded?

I have even manually excluded the virtual environment (`.venv` and friends) directories.

[image]

The files are *still* being searched under that `.venv` directory

[image]

I am on PyCharm Professional 2021.3.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** For readers who are busy and just want a **quick-fix** to get on with their work I usually recommend [narrowing search using scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html#limit_search) thereby you can explicitly exclude any paths that are polluting your search results.

I think this might be a PyCharm 2021.3.1 specific bug (see [this excellent answer to the PY-51643 issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-51643/Find-in-Files-and-other-dialogs-don%27t-ignore-excluded-directorie#focus=Comments-27-5661944.0-0) on JetBrains bugtracker). It should be possible to fix the issue by manually configuring some IDE settings, however the solution is dependent on a very specific interpreter/project setup so reproducing the conditions of the bug requires setting up an entire environment.